# XP command prompt : redirect a file to STDOUT

Tags: command-line

I want to do the opposite of everybody ( laugh )
I start open-erp with a command line like :

```
C:\OpenERPAllInOne\Server>openerp-server.exe --log-file=outputfile
```

but the problem is that with Windows it only does output to a file.

Is there any way to redirect a file to the STDOUT.
For example (it doesn't work but this is the way I see it working) :

```
C:\OpenERPAllInOne\Server>openerp-server.exe --log-file=STDOUT
```

and then see directly the output to the command line.

I can't make it work ! Any idea ?

Thanks,

Olivier

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if it still works, try CON (hope it was that) as filename

Answer (score 0):

That would be a function of the openerp-server.exe program.

If it's default output is to a file, then there isn't anything you can do about that.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that OpenERP uses getopt_long and confirms to GNU standards. If it does, then the following should work:

```
openerp-server --log-file=-
```

(a dash is usually used to represent STDOUT in GNU, Linux and UNIX programs.)

Comment: It's with Windows (with Linux it already outputs everyting to STDOUT), with "--log_file=CON" it works :)

Comment: It's kinda equivalent... "-" (linux) == /dev/stdout (linux) == CON (w32). Odd how they call stdout "*con*sole"

Comment: It is actually very old stuff from MS-DOS 5.0 I think. There is also PRN (remember dot matrix printers that can print line by line), COMM1 and COMM2. These are special files like /dev/stdout for MS-DOS. After all these years its interesting that they still work.

Comment: Now I checked them its COM1 and COM2 not COMM1 and COMM2

Answer (score 0):

If you can't get the server to output to the standard output you could monitor the log file with [`tail][1]`.

If you run:

```
tail -f c:\path\to\logfile.txt
```

in another window then you can see the contents of the file as they are written.

`tail` doesn't come with Windows as standard but [you can download a free port of `tail` for Windows here](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/coreutils.htm).

Comment: this only works if the log file is not locked and the process that is writing the log file, flushes it after each line.  However worth a try..

Answer (score 0):

for windows there is a configuration file for OpenERP Server,
like openerp-server.conf in the directory where you have installed the Open ERP

```
like c:\Program Files\OpenERP Server\openerp-server.conf OR
C:\documents and settings\USER\OpenERP Server\oepenrp-server.conf
```

you need to edit that file and set the --log-file paramter to None or False, and probably you might also try out something like this

```
C:\OpenERPAllInOne\Server>openerp-server.exe --log-file=False
```

that should work, but not sure whether it will work or not.!!

Comment: It doesn't work because I when I asked this question I was IN the Tiny house, in formation in Belgium and the developper himself told us he didn't know how to do it under Windows (they all use Linux, not Windows). (Don't hesitate to edit my comment to make it proper English)

Comment: did you try to modify the original config file from start menu-> openerp server -> edit configuration and set the log-file to None it worked for me

Comment: no i didn't but i'll check it out later thanks for the hint :)